# How do you handle divs that are mostly the same but have some subtle differences?

Tags: html, css, optimization, coding-style

I want to make 5 or 6 divs that will contain an image and some static text.  However, I want to alternate which side of the div the image is on.  So the first div it would be on the left, the next one on the right, and so on.

Is it best to generalize them all into a class, and then hash out the differences inside that class?  Or should I just create two different classes which would easily solve the problem but make the code a bit harder to maintain?  Is there a generally accepted way to handle these sorts of things?

I have tended to handle this sort of thing by creating two separate classes, but I'm not sure that this is the best way to do it and I'm wondering if there are better ways to approach the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try some CSS like this:

```
section > div:nth-of-type(odd) > img {
    float:left;
}

section > div:nth-of-type(even) > img {
    float:right;
}
```

... and HTML like this:

```
<body>
    <section>
        <div>
            <img src='xxx.png'>
            <p>Text</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src='xxx.png'>
            <p>Text</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src='xxx.png'>
            <p>Text</p>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `:nth-child` to specifically target a class.

You can alter the code to your preferences by checking this: [**NthMaster**](http://nthmaster.com/)

```css
.item:nth-child(even) > span {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
    <span>Text</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
    <span>Text</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
    <span>Text</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
    <span>Text</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
    <span>Text</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
    <span>Text</span>
  </div>
</div>
```